# Streaming video only fails to load with a short duration

Tags: apache, h.264

I use jwplayer and apache2.2 with h264 streaming module I downloaded from http://blog.codingmafia.com/?p=167. I have been messing around the 'start' and 'end' functions which allow you to stream a segment of a video.

I have noticed a bizarre phenomenon. It allowed me to play a few seconds near the beginning of the video. But when I pushed back the play times from 15-19 to 1115-1119 (seconds), it returned an error message saying `Video not found or access denied: video.mp4?start=1115&end=1119.`

I have tried different time sets and durations and it seems that the duration it requires to work gets longer as the video rolls toward the end.

What can explain this error?

Comment: by the way, the video was about 40 mins long.

Comment: oh.. another. when i trim the video by using start and end parameters and then stream, last few seconds go missing..wouldnt it be related to the original issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to my video's encoding. the aforementioned h.264 streaming module seems to locate the closest 'I frames'(complete image frame) for start and end and cut a portion staring and ending at the I frames.
When these two I frames are actually one, it returns null type of value, hence the above error.
Re-encoding the video inserting an I frame in every 6 frames solved the problem.